# Facebook Login Button Causing JS Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, web

I used [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) to setup a login button for facebook.  When I click the button, I'm getting this error: "permission denied" on this line: `b.fbCallID=a.id` in this

```
FB.UIServer._loadedNodes[a.id]=b;if(a.params)b.fbCallID=a.id;
```

Drilling back to see where it may be caused from, I see it can be caused from this:

```
FB.login(FB.bind(this._authCallback,this),{perms:this._attr.perms,scope:this._attr.scope});}
```

Because this._attr is undefined.  I am using this example exactly:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Any idea why?  Do I need an explicit permission for logging in?  This is the only Facebook code in the application so far...  Currently the Facebook application registration points to my local machine on localhost.

Thanks.